# How do I convert a GP to a string and back again using DEAP in Python?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming, deap

I'm doing a project in Genetic Programming and I need to be able to convert a genetic program (of class deap.creator.Individual) to string, change some things (while keeping the problem 100% syntactically aligned with DEAP), and then put it back into a population of individuals for further evolution.

However, I've only been able to convert my string back to class gp.PrimitiveTree using the from_string method.
The only constructors for creator.Individual I see generate entire populations blindly or construct an Individual from an existing Individual/s. No methods to only create one individual from an **existing** gp.PrimitiveTree.

So, does anybody have any idea how I go about that?

Note: Individual is self-defined, but it is standard across all DEAP examples and is created using

```
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", gp.PrimitiveTree, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)
```

Answer (score 2):

After many many hours I believe I've figured this out.

So, I'd become confused between two of the DEAP modules: 'creator' and 'toolbox'.
In order for me to create an individual with a given PrimitiveTree I simply needed to do:

```
creator.Individual(myPrimativeTree)
```

What you **do not** do is:

```
toolbox.individual(myPrimativeTree)
```

as that usually gets setup as the initialiser itself, and thus doesn't take arguments.

I hope that this can save somebody a decent chunk of time at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Individual to string:** str(individual)

**In order to create an Individual from a string**: Primitive Tree has class method from_string:
https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/gp.html#deap.gp.PrimitiveTree.from_string

In your Deap evolution, to create an individual from string, you can try something like(note use of creator vs toolbox):

```
creator.Individual.from_string("add(IN1, IN2)", pset)
```

But the individual expression, as a string, needs to be such as it would if you did str(individual), aka stick to your pset when creating your string. So in my above example string I believe you would need to have a pset similar to:

```
pset = gp.PrimitiveSetTyped("MAIN", [float]*2, float, "IN")
pset.addPrimitive(operator.add, [float,float], float)
```